# How to receive number when Twilio make a phone call?

Tags: node.js, twilio

Language: Node js

---

1. Follow this make_phone_call.js, and replace url to my create voice.xml

```js
// Download the Node helper library from twilio.com/docs/node/install
// These consts are your accountSid and authToken from twilio.com/user/account
const accountSid = 'AC36861400a21a3ee42437f446015cd183';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const Twilio = require('twilio');
const client = new Twilio(accountSid, authToken);

client.api.calls
  .create({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1/docs/voice.xml',
    to: '+14155551212',
    from: '+15017122661',
  })
  .then(call => console.log(call.sid));
```

2. voice.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather timeout="10" numDigits="1">
        <Say>Please press any key to continue.</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

3. But when I excute "node make_phone_call.js", and return sid.

```js
-(~/proj/nodejs/twilio)
└> node make_call_response.js
CA5bbd4ef648d6f26b3302486ed0ff14ac
```

4. If client User Press "9", and I don't know, where i receive the number?

Comment: Taking a look at the docs: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather It looks like a post request will be made to the TwiML url which would be http://127.0.0.1/docs/voice.xml

Comment: I try that( twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) before, but i still can't receive number from client user.

Comment: You'll need a URL that twillio's server can access I'd use https://ngrok.com/ for local testing

Comment: I setup ngrok, but i don't know how to link twilio and ngork, do you have any instruction to help me?

Comment: I setup url for this(https://drv.tw/~ddtrng@gmail.com/gd/Web/index.html), I think it's same as ngork. I can make phone call successful  already, just can't receive number "9" from client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Generalhenry has made some good points in the comments, I just want to tie that all up together.

First up, in your code that makes the call, you set the URL to `http://127.0.0.1/docs/voice.xml`. Twilio will attempt to make an HTTP request (webhook) to that URL when the call connects. However, `127.0.0.1` is your local IP address and it is not publicly accessible, so Twilio won't be able to reach it.

I suggest installing [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), which is a tool that gives you a public URL that can tunnel through to your development server. [I'm a big fan of ngrok myself](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/6-awesome-reasons-to-use-ngrok-when-testing-webhooks.html).

Once you have ngrok set up, you then need to do some other bits to use [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather).

We need to update your TwiML first. When `<Gather>` receives input from the user it will make a request to a URL you can define using the [`action` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-action). Without that URL defined it will make a request to the existing URL. Let's add an `action` attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather timeout="10" numDigits="1" action="/twiml/action">
        <Say>Please press any key to continue.</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

It looks like you are just hosting a static XML file there. That's fine for your initial XML, but when you want to retrieve the digits the user entered you will need a web application. Since you are using Node.js I recommend [Express](http://expressjs.com/).

We need to build an endpoint that Twilio can make a request to which allows you to extract the pressed digit. Twilio will send the request with a body parameter `Digits` which contains the key. Let's see how you could use Express to extract that parameter.

```
const app = require('express')();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

app.post('/twiml/action', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.Digits);

  // return more TwiML
});

app.listen()
```

`Digits` is a url encoded parameter set as part of the body. We parse that from the body using body-parser and you can then do what you want with the result.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: I try your instruction, it's can fetch number when user pressed, thank you very much.

Comment: Hooray! Glad that helped. Hope the rest of your app goes well.